# How can I remove stubborn nails from baseboard?

Tags: baseboard, nails

I have tried pounding the nails out through the front, they don't budge.  I have tried pulling the nails through the back with pliers, they break off. The baseboard is a laminate from old laminate flooring.  The nails were obviously put in with a pneumatic nailer.

Any suggestions for removing the nails so I can replace the baseboards would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I usually use a pair of end cutting pliers, to pull the nails out the back.

[image]

The face of the tool is slightly rounded, which allows for a good rocking motion.

Just grab the nail **gently** with the pliers, as close to the work piece as possible. Rocking the tool on it's rounded face generates quite a bit of leverage, allowing you to pull most nails out. Just remember not to squeeze too hard, or you'll simply cut the nail off.

Comment: This is my usual method. I've heard them referred to commonly as "end nippers."

Comment: @Doresoom That's how I usually refer to them, but I try to use the proper term in answers.

Comment: Channel lock pliers work well in the same way - one side is curved, and you don't have to worry so much about cutting the nail.

Comment: They're also often called carpenter's pincers. Some designed specifically for nail pulling (not as sharp, longer handles) are also available.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a claw hammer.

An also if you needed you can put a block under the pliers/hammer for more leverage an to protect what ever it is
Can make it a little easier.

Or cut/snap the nails off and punch them out with a nail punch.

Comment: A paint stick behind pliers was enough for me.